# How to make html email responsive in gmail?

Tags: responsive-design, gmail, html-email

I've built an html email which is perfect in yahoo but not in gmail. As gmail does not support header style how will i add media query. But I got many email which are responsive in gmail mobile. How they made that? what's the way?

Comment: "Responsive" behavior is not possible in Gmail (because of the lack of header support), only something "scalable". [Link: https://litmus.com/blog/responsive-scalable-email-design-whats-the-difference]

Answer (score 0):

Build the email to fit gmail app first and then use media queries and conditional code to make it work in everything else.

Mobile first design is the only way to make a responsive email in gmail app - see great example [here](http://labs.actionrocket.co/the-hybrid-coding-approach-2)

Answer (score 0):

**Hybrid Design** achieves a responsive, shape-shifting layout without using media queries. At its core, it uses max-width and min-width to impose rigid baselines (allowing some movement) and imposes a fixed, wide width for Outlook who is shackled to desktop anyway. Once a mobile-friendly baseline is set, media queries progressively enhance the email further in clients that support it (like iOS Mail).

Here is a basic 2-column scaffolding from [Fabio Carneiro's code samples on GitHub](https://github.com/fcarneiro/tedc15_template) (all credit to him!):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <body style="margin:0;">
  <center>
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">




    <!-- // 2-COLUMN SCAFFOLD [CENTERING, FLUID] -->
    <tr>
     <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%">
      <!--[if mso]>
      <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="660">
      <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" width="660">
      <![endif]-->
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:660px;">
       <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0;">
         <!--// DEVELOPER NOTES:
          1. Setting font-size:0; is necessary to ensure
             that there is no extra spacing introduced
             between the centering divs that wrap each
             of the columns. //-->

         <!--[if mso]>
         <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="660">
         <tr>
         <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
         <![endif]-->
         <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:240px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
          <!--// DEVELOPER NOTES:
           1. To have each column center upon stacking,
              wrap them in individual divs, set the same
              max-width and width as the table within it,
              and set display to inline-block; using
              vertical-align is optional.

           2. Setting min-width determines when the two
              columns of this block will wrap; in this
              case, when the total available width is
              less than or equal to 480px. //-->

          <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:330px;">
           <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
 
             <!-- // REPLACE WITH BLOCK -->
             <p style="background-color:#2BAADF; color:#FFFFFF; font:16px Helvetica, sans-serif, normal; margin:0 !important; padding:10px;">LEFT</p>
             <!-- REPLACE WITH BLOCK // -->
 
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if mso]>
         </td>
         <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
         <![endif]-->
         <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:240px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
          <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:330px;">
           <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
 
             <!-- // REPLACE WITH BLOCK -->
             <p style="background-color:#51BBE5; color:#FFFFFF; font:16px Helvetica, sans-serif, normal; margin:0 !important; padding:10px;">RIGHT</p>
             <!-- REPLACE WITH BLOCK // --> 
 
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if mso]>
         </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
         <![endif]-->
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <!--[if mso]>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <![endif]-->
     </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 2-COLUMN SCAFFOLD [CENTERING, FLUID] // -->




   </table>
  </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

There are more scaffolds and patterns in that repo and elsewhere, but this shows the basic principle in action.