# Fluid Design Max-Width Changing To 100% On Break (HTML EMAIL)

Tags: css, html-email, fluid-layout, hybrid

I found this related question that has a great solution where there is a two column design that stacks upon reaching the threshold of 320px. This is great; however, I'm curious if there's a way to use a width property in order to replicate this behavior of two columns stacking, but instead of the widths being constrained to 320px, they become width 100% after stacking on each other. The question can be found here: [How to make html email responsive in gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532517/how-to-make-html-email-responsive-in-gmail)

and the code can be found below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body style="margin:0;">
        <center>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">




                <!-- // 2-COLUMN SCAFFOLD [CENTERING, FLUID] -->
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%">
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="660">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="660">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:660px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0;">
                                    <!--// DEVELOPER NOTES:
                                        1. Setting font-size:0; is necessary to ensure
                                           that there is no extra spacing introduced
                                           between the centering divs that wrap each
                                           of the columns. //-->

                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="660">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                    <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:240px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
                                        <!--// DEVELOPER NOTES:
                                            1. To have each column center upon stacking,
                                               wrap them in individual divs, set the same
                                               max-width and width as the table within it,
                                               and set display to inline-block; using
                                               vertical-align is optional.

                                            2. Setting min-width determines when the two
                                               columns of this block will wrap; in this
                                               case, when the total available width is
                                               less than or equal to 480px. //-->

                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:330px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top">

                                                    <!-- // REPLACE WITH BLOCK -->
                                                    <p style="background-color:#2BAADF; color:#FFFFFF; font:16px Helvetica, sans-serif, normal; margin:0 !important; padding:10px;">LEFT</p>
                                                    <!-- REPLACE WITH BLOCK // -->

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                    <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:240px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:330px;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top">

                                                    <!-- // REPLACE WITH BLOCK -->
                                                    <p style="background-color:#51BBE5; color:#FFFFFF; font:16px Helvetica, sans-serif, normal; margin:0 !important; padding:10px;">RIGHT</p>
                                                    <!-- REPLACE WITH BLOCK // -->  

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 2-COLUMN SCAFFOLD [CENTERING, FLUID] // -->




            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

I recommend testing it out to see what I'm referring to. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. You can use media queries to target specific HTML elements with a class. I have given a class of FullWidth and when the screens size reaches 480 pixels, the blocks will be full width of the screen.

A few things to note:

- This code **will work** on latest Gmail app, iOS (generic email client) and Android 4.4 and below(generic email client).
- Move the media query into the head of the HTML.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
.FullWidth{width:100% !important;max-width:100% !important;}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<body style="margin:0;">
        <center>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                <!-- // 2-COLUMN SCAFFOLD [CENTERING, FLUID] -->
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%">
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="660">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="660">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:660px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0;">
                                    <!--// DEVELOPER NOTES:
                                        1. Setting font-size:0; is necessary to ensure
                                           that there is no extra spacing introduced
                                           between the centering divs that wrap each
                                           of the columns. //-->

                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="660">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                    <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:240px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;" class="FullWidth">
                                        <!--// DEVELOPER NOTES:
                                            1. To have each column center upon stacking,
                                               wrap them in individual divs, set the same
                                               max-width and width as the table within it,
                                               and set display to inline-block; using
                                               vertical-align is optional.

                                            2. Setting min-width determines when the two
                                               columns of this block will wrap; in this
                                               case, when the total available width is
                                               less than or equal to 480px. //-->

                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:330px;" class="FullWidth">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top">

                                                    <!-- // REPLACE WITH BLOCK -->
                                                    <p style="background-color:#2BAADF; color:#FFFFFF; font:16px Helvetica, sans-serif, normal; margin:0 !important; padding:10px;">LEFT</p>
                                                    <!-- REPLACE WITH BLOCK // -->

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                    <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:50%; min-width:240px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;" class="FullWidth">
                                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:330px;" class="FullWidth">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" valign="top">

                                                    <!-- // REPLACE WITH BLOCK -->
                                                    <p style="background-color:#51BBE5; color:#FFFFFF; font:16px Helvetica, sans-serif, normal; margin:0 !important; padding:10px;">RIGHT</p>
                                                    <!-- REPLACE WITH BLOCK // -->  

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 2-COLUMN SCAFFOLD [CENTERING, FLUID] // -->




            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any questions

Cheers

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, I'm aware of media queries; however, whenever I test an email with them they are ignored by Gmail. I believe this is because they exist in style tags in the head and style tags are ignored by Gmail... but media queries can't be put anywhere else except for in another CSS file which isn't good HTML email development practice, so I'm kind of stuck between a rock and a hard place with this one. The code you provided above behaves in the same way it did originally. It works in the browser but when opening in Gmail the media tags are ignored.

Comment: The media queries Wil be ignored if it has errors according to Gmail and only the first one will be read. Gmail is very strict when using media queries. One example I can give it if your max width has spcaes then the whole query is ignored.